Bean Shell Post Processer of a test Fragment every time taking same role credentials
Here I am trying to achieve use Same Login Test Fragment for different roles along with BeanShell Post Processor.
The issue is  every time picking the  Employee Role credentials  even though Setup Thread Group1_Admin  No: Of 1 &  Setup Thread Group1_Employye No: Of 2 for Total 3 users
Here is the Test Design
Test Plan
Setup Thread Group 1- Admin
 Login_Credentials_Admin CSV Config

 Login_access_Admin CSV Config

 user Defined Variables: user_type : Admin

 Include Controller(Login Test Fragment)

Setup Thread Group 2- Employee
 Login_Credentials_Employee CSV Config

 Login_access_Employee CSV Config

 user Defined Variables: user_type : Employee

 Include Controller(Login Test Fragment) 

The actual code of BeanShell Post Processor per role saved in individual CSV files and passing in the below code
Here is the BeanShell Post Processor
// Read the file path of the BeanShell script based on user type
String userType = vars.get("user_type");
String beanshellPostProcessorFile = "";
if (userType.equals("Admin")) {
    beanshellPostProcessorFile = vars.get("beanshell_post_processor_file_admin");
} else if (userType.equals("Clinical_Employee")) {
    beanshellPostProcessorFile = vars.get("beanshell_post_processor_file_XXXX_employee");
}

try {
    // Read the contents of the BeanShell script file
    String scriptCode = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(beanshellPostProcessorFile), "UTF-8"); // Use "UTF-8" directly

    // Evaluate the BeanShell code
    eval(scriptCode);
    
    // Log information
    log.info("Dyanmic BeanShell PostProcessor File: " + beanshellPostProcessorFile + "; user: " + vars.get("user_type"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Error reading script file: " + e.getMessage());
} 


As per User Defined Variables documentation:

The User Defined Variables element lets you define an initial set of variables, just as in the Test Plan.
Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they are - are processed at the start.

So I expect that you will always get the value of the Employee guy
You need another approach for defining user_type like User Parameters or Set Variables Action or CSV file.
With regards to Beanshell, since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting so consider migrating. More information: Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?
